# Generalizing function to reuse with different elements

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How can I generalize these two functions to use in identical divs?

```
showNotifyText = () => {
 const { showNotifyText } = this.state;
 this.setState({ showNotifyText: !showNotifyText });
};
showRoutineAvailabilityText = () => {
 const { showRoutineAvailabilityText } = this.state;
 this.setState({ showRoutineAvailabilityText: !showRoutineAvailabilityText });
};
```

Comment: There's not anything specifically that keeps these functions from being reused. You would just need to make your JSX use the same state properties in multiple components or multiple places in the same component.

Comment: It's unclear what *to use in identical divs* means in your case. An example that includes all related components would be suitable.

Answer (score 1):

Using `this.state` in `setState` is antipattern because [`setState` is asynchronous](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/11527). If new state derives from previous one, `setState` function should be used.

It could be either generalized method:

```
toggleStateProperty = key => {
  this.setState(state => ({ [key]: !state[key] }));
};
```

Or higher-order function:

```
toggleStatePropertyFactory = key => function () {
  this.setState(state => ({ [key]: !state[key] }));
};

...

toggleShowNotifyText  = toggleStatePropertyFactory('showNotifyText');

toggleRoutineAvailabilityText = toggleStatePropertyFactory('showRoutineAvailabilityText');
```

In case the method is supposed to be passed as a callback, the second option is preferable because it already binds the method to specific key:

```
<div onclick={this.toggleShowNotifyText}/>
```

vs

```
<div onclick={() => this.toggleStateProperty('showNotifyText')}/>
```

Comment: I'd name it `toggle…`, but otherwise I'd do it exactly like this :-)

Comment: @Bergi I'd name it like that too )) Not sure why I typed 'trigger'.

Answer (score 0):

To generalize the method you could try adding the state key in the template as data, then read it inside the event handler:

```
onClick = (event) => {
  const key = event.target.dataset.key;
  const value = this.state[key];
  this.setState({ [key]: !value });
}

render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <div onClick={this.onClick} data-key="showRoutineAvailabilityText">click</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```